# In bootstrap navigation When click on the nav,the class get active but the page does not change as per the given url

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navlist">
                                 <li>
                                    <a  href="">
                                            <i title="" class="fa fa-home-o fa-3x"></i><br>
Dashboard                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <a  href="form.html">
                                            <i title="" class="fa fa-building-o fa-3x"></i><br>
                                            Corporate
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="form.html">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-plus-square fa-3x"></i><br>
                                           Offers</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="login.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="page-blank.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-square-o"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="invoice.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Invoice</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="princing-table.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Princing Table</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="faq.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-sun-o"></i> FAQ</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="register.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-plus"></i> Register</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="404.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-warning"></i> 404 Error</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="500.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-warning"></i> 500 Error</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {

    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
        $parent.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

css i have used

```
<style>.active { color: red; background:#000; }</style>
```

In bootstrap navigation When click on the nav,the class get active but the page does not change as per the given url
How can i resolve this.Navigation get show active and page change also

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the page won't change because of the preventDefault(), even if it did the class would be lost on page reload. Do you have access to the HTML? Depending on the scale of the project you could give an element on each page an attr e.g. pageX, then on document ready or document load you could get the attr and compare this to the menu items and add a class to the matched one. This is only really viable for a small project or one you can generate these classes automatically, perhaps via a cms.

Answer (score 0):

This method e.preventDefault() prevent clicked anchors take the browser to new URL. If you want active navigation menu before redirection, use following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav li a").on("click", function () {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

in order to override default Active class, use !important for background color.

```
.active {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from @Amir and @samisonline I think it's clear that the `e.preventDefault()` it's the reason why the link is not functioning properly.

**Furthermore** it seems that what you want to achieve is something differently, which I understand as adding the `active` class to the correct `nav` element after the route has been selected (after the redirect).

To achieve this you can use the `window.location.pathname` to get the current link the page is on, like so.

Taking that you nav is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="login.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="page-blank.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-square-o"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="invoice.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Invoice</a></li>
  <li><a href="princing-table.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Princing Table</a></li>
  <li><a href="faq.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-sun-o"></i> FAQ</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="register.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-plus"></i> Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="404.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-warning"></i> 404 Error</a></li>
  <li><a href="500.html"><i title="" data-original-title="" class="fa fa-warning"></i> 500 Error</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the user navigates to `login.html` for instance the url will be now: `http://yoursite.com/login.html`

So you can use the following jQuery code to add the `active` class to you `nav`:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul.dropdown-menu li a[href^="/' + window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Hope it helps! 
Cheers.